# Implementing AJAX into posts

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am building a custom post type (CPT) that requires a form that users may choose to submit. Regardless, I want any user to be able to see the current summation of the results. This is similar to how to codex article on AJAX says WordPress uses it..

"Several themes and plugins also use Ajax; for instance, some post rating plugins use Ajax to store the visitor's rating in the database and then display an updated average rating." - http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX

How can I create an element that shows an average rating from user inputs on a CPT entry?

Comment: Have you tried searching how to do it? There are lots of tutorial to do it..

Comment: @blo I have, but haven't found a source that provides structured details